# Execute functions in a list as a chain

Tags: python, function, composition

In Python I defined these functions:

```
def foo_1(p): return p + 1
def foo_2(p): return p + 1
def foo_3(p): return p + 1
def foo_4(p): return p + 1
def foo_5(p): return p + 1
```

I want to execute these functions in a chain like this:

```
foo_1(foo_2(foo_3(foo_4(foo_5(1)))))
```

I'd like to specify these functions as a list, executing those functions in a chain with a precise sequence. This is what I've tried:

```
lf = [Null,foo_1,foo_2,foo_3,foo_4,foo_5]  # Null is for +1 issue here

def execu(lst, seq, raw_para):
    # in some way

execu(lf,(1,2,3,4,5), 1)   # = foo_1(foo_2(foo_3(foo_4(foo_5(1)))))
execu(lf,(1,2,3), 1)       # = foo_1(foo_2(foo_3(1)))
execu(lf,(3,3,3), 1)       # = foo_3(foo_3(foo_3(1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def execu(lst, seq, raw_para):
  return reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), reversed(operator.itemgetter(*seq)(lst)), raw_para)
```

Comment: `reduce()` handles the elements from beginning to end. Your example shows them being invoked from end to beginning.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to write code like this.  @dugres shows the approach which is sane, obvious, and instantly understandable.  This is just trying to be clever, to no benefit and resulting in very hard-to-understand code.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) for this:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), list_of_functions, initial_value)
```

Like so:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), reversed([foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, ...]), 1)
```

Note that If you want to apply the functions in the order of `foo_1(foo_2(etc...))`, you have to make sure that `foo_1` is the last element of the list of functions. Therefore I use `reversed` in the latter example.

Comment: Unfortunately this will compose the functions in the wrong order. `...(foo_3(foo_2(foo_1(1))))`

Comment: Good call, Ignacio, I'll add a `reversed` call.

Answer (score 5):

No need for "Null" in "lf".

```
def execu(lst, seq, raw_para):  
    para = raw_para  
    for i in reversed(seq):  
        para = lst[i](para)
    return para
```

Comment: +1, but I think 1st None (Null?) is required, or use `lst[i-1]`

Comment: `seq` values are indexes into `lst`, so no change is needed here.  Rather, if you remove the unnecessary None from the OP's list you also need to shift the indexes down one to match.  I'd suggest removing `para` and renaming `raw_para` to `para` to simplify.

Comment: This code has got to be the first thing everyone thinks of.  I don't know why everyone else felt it was an improvement to bring reduce and lambda into the picture.

Comment: #Glenn Maynard, thanks for your idea and programming code style suggestion, dugres's solution is more traditional and natural idea similar as a recursion solution. It is OK and easy to use but I think the python beginner such as me may think the reduce() is much cool. Same as the first time I know the List Comprehensions in python, that's why I accepted the right answer to the reduce, if there's 2 acceptable answers, I will give another on to dugres.